# Writing array list to shared prefs without overwriting

Tags: java, android

I am writing an arraylist to shared prefs each time my app is opened i.e in `onCreate()`. Here is my code -

In `onCreate()`,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       Log.d("hi","List details : " + myList);
       Prefs.storeDeviceDetails(myList);

       Prefs.retrieveDeviceDetails();
       Log.d("hi","Retrieved from Shared Prefs " + Prefs.retrieveDeviceDetails());

    }
```

Here is my code for Shared Preferences -

```
public void storeDeviceDetails(final ArrayList<String> deviceDetails) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("devicePrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonText = gson.toJson(deviceDetails);
    editor.putString("detailsKey", jsonText);
    Log.d("hi","Data written in Prefs = " + jsonText);
    editor.apply();
}

public String[] retrieveDeviceDetails() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("devicePrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String text = prefs.getString("detailsKey", null);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    details = gson.fromJson(text, String[].class);
    Log.d("hi","Array values = " + details);
    return details;
}
```

The Logs printed are -

```
D/hi: List details : [samsung, hero2lte, hero2ltexx, SM-G935F, 7.0, 2017-03-21 13:24:26]

 D/hi: Data written in Prefs = ["samsung","hero2lte","hero2ltexx","SM-G935F","7.0","2017-03-21 13:24:26","samsung","hero2lte","hero2ltexx","SM-G935F","7.0","2017-03-21 13:24:26"]

 D/hi: Array values = [Ljava.lang.String;@8982aeb

 D/hi: Array values = [Ljava.lang.String;@2a01048

 D/hi: Retrieved from Shared Prefs = [Ljava.lang.String;@2a01048
```

Everytime I open the app, my list has some data which is as per `List details` log. Data written to prefs should not be overwritten. 
My problem is -

1) If I open the app, `Data written in Prefs` log should have data of all the time I have opened the app. That means if i opened the app 10 times, I must have 10 sets of data which I dont have. 
I always have 2 sets of data.

2) When I read from shared prefs, I only read the latest value from `String []` and not all the values.

How do I overcomes this problems?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your data to be overwritten. retrieve info from sharedPreferences add it to the list and then store it.

SharedPref basically makes an XML file in your app and saves it in key value pairs. (detailsKey, devicePrefs being your key).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are overriding your `SharedPreferences` is that you are actually overriding it.

```
 String jsonText = gson.toJson(deviceDetails);
 editor.putString("detailsKey", jsonText);
```

That will replace the `String` in `detailsKey` with `jsonText`. So you possibly want to retrieve the current value and append your new String.

Something like

```
 SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("devicePrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String jsonText = gson.toJson(deviceDetails);
 String currentText = pref.getString("detailsKey", null);
 if(currentText != null) // combine jsonText and currentText however you need it
 pref.edit().putString("detailsKey", jsonText);
 Log.d("hi","Data written in Prefs = " + jsonText);
 editor.apply();
```

Comment: Its still the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Create an integer with value 0 every time you write into shared preferences write that too and load next time value of i from shared preferences first so by that you can track number of times you write in shared preferences then when you write your data in shared preferences append your key by concatenating i at the end so every time value of key is changed you got another entry in shared preferences.Upon loading loop for values of present i and everytime appent i with key in loop. You will get what you want. I hope you understand what I just said :) It will surely workout give it a try.